# Magento 2.2. mobile specific logo

Tags: magento2.2, logo

Does anyone know if there's a built in way to define a logo specifically for mobile?

I read somewhere that you could place a logo-small.svg file in app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/web/images/ but I've not had any success with this yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logo image resides in the following location on the server. Any image file with by that name and at that location is used as the theme logo.

Path:

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/web/images/logo.svg
```

Magento uses a `svg` image by default. 
**This should look fine on every device, even on devices with a high dppx.** But

For as far as I know, **Magento does not offer a solution to provide a different image or different dimensions for mobile from the backend**.

But If the default solution doesn't suit you, you can add your own by modifying the `logo.phtml` file. This file should be added in your custom theme at `/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml.`

Or `_theme.less` file in my custom theme to make it work:

```
// Mobile Logo Fix
.logo img {
   width: auto;
}
```